# Convert single apix to dash in permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I noticed that by default if I create a page with title "It's great" the generated permalink will be `its-great`. I would like it to become `it-s-great` by default.

Where can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stripped out with [`sanitize_title_with_dashes()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cde61269235ba33355cc96b8eaff2a0164aee3c0/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1953) through the `sanitize_title` filter at priority 10 ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cde61269235ba33355cc96b8eaff2a0164aee3c0/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L205)), so you can replace it with a dash, just before with:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', function( $title )
{
    return str_replace( "'", "-", $title );
}, 9 );
```